# Regarding mern stack project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, syntax-error, web-frontend

```
Error Message

./node_modules/@mui/utils/esm/exactProp.js 

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:4) 

You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

|   }

|   return {

|     ...propTypes,

|     [specialProperty]: props => {

|  const unsupportedProps = Object.keys(props).filter(prop =>
 !propTypes.hasOwnProperty(prop));
```

When I tried to run my frontend part of the project I encountered this error.
I tried to update build tools like babel and see if the configurations were correct but
I did not find any error there

Here is the code of file that is cauing the problem exactProps.js

```
 // This module is based on https://github.com/airbnb/prop-types-exact repository.

// However, in order to reduce the number of dependencies and to remove some extra safe checks 

// the module was forked.

const specialProperty = 'exact-prop: \u200b';

export default function exactProp(propTypes) {

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

    return propTypes;

  }

  return {

    ...propTypes,

    [specialProperty]: props => {

    const unsupportedProps = Object.keys(props).filter(prop =>!propTypes.hasOwnProperty(prop));

      if (unsupportedProps.length > 0) {

   return new Error(`The following props are not supported: ${unsupportedProps.map(prop=>`\`${prop}\``).join(', ')}. Please remove them.`);

      }

      return null;

    }

  };

}
```

I tried using chatgpt to see if it can solve the error but it says the error is in the configurations.
I think since the code is from an old project, some files and functions are deprecated which is causing the issue with the spread syntax in the exactProps.js file but I don't know how to fix this issue 
please help

Comment: Can you please share the code where you are using this? The node_modules are not causing the error, it might be due to the wrong use of props.